# Unable to load workbook (<TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.chart.axis.NumericAxis'>)

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsm', data_only=True)
sheets = wb.sheetnames
x = wb[sheets[0]]
```

But I got this error :

```
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.chart.axis.NumericAxis'>
```

What I understood is that `openpyxl` cannot open sheet with graph, not anymore at least.

But I only need on sheet, and there is no graph inside.

Is there a way to directly tell `openpyxl` to open only one sheet and not waiting after `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=True)`

Or if you have other ideas ?

Apparently it's based on the source code so I'm kind of stuck with that. Source :

https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1360

Comment: You can use read-only mode.

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: It's covered in the openpyxl documentation.

Comment: I will try, than you for the tip :)

Comment: It work, ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If that package has a bug which prevents you from using it on a full file, and you can't find another package to use instead, you can try to work around the problem by finding another package that allows you to open an Excel workbook and extract a single sheet from it into a temporary workbook file, and then make the openpyxl calls using that temporary file.

Comment: Have you a package in mind ? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @RandallCloud - Sorry, no particular package in mind. But when you work in software, you constantly have to work around bugs in other people's code. :)

Comment: Yeah I know :D thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As Charlie Clark said, read-only mode helps (solved the issue for me when opening a XLSM file).
This should work just fine, and possibly faster:

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsm', data_only=True, read_only=True)
sheets = wb.sheetnames
x = wb[sheets[0]]
```

Be sure to [read the openpyxl documentation on Optimised Modes](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html) because there are some caveats in read-only / write-only modes.